# $\int f$ notation for integration

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, notation

If we have a single-variable function $f$ how does this sort of notation work?

$$\int_0^x f$$

I assume if we have a number $x$ we can take the area under the graph of $f$ as we vary the upper bound $x$.

However can we express the indefinite integral of $f$?

$$\int f$$

Would $\int f$ be the (general form) function $F$ such that:

$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$

In this case, is integration done on 'values' such as $f(x)$ or on functions such as $f$? As differentiation is defined explicitly on functions.

Comment: $\int_0^x f$ is just a shorter way of writing $\int_0^x f(t)~\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: But we should not exaggerate the laziness and write out $f(t)dt$ to rule out that $f(x)dx$ is meant which would lead to a quite different result.

Comment: OP has asked [a number of questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1096856/user1007028?tab=questions) related to how variables are used in function notation. This is fine, of course. I mention it for broader context, and as it may help others avoid giving responses OP has already seen.

Comment: @Blue thanks for this